# convert bipartite graph to adjacency matrix spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to convert edge list which is in the following format

```
data = [('a', 'developer'),
     ('b', 'tester'),
    ('b', 'developer'),
     ('c','developer'),
     ('c', 'architect')]
```

where the adjacency matrix will be in the form of

```
      developer     tester    architect
 a        1            0          0
 b        1            1          0
 c        1            0          1
```

I want to store the matrix in the following format

```
 1    0    0
 1    1    0
 1    0    1
```

I've tried it using GraphX

```
def pageHash(title:String )  = title.toLowerCase.replace(" ","").hashCode.toLong


val edges: RDD[Edge[String]] = sc.textFile("/user/query.csv").map { line => 
  val row = line.split(",") 
  Edge(pageHash(row(0)), pageHash(row(1)), "1") 
} 
val graph: Graph[Int, String] = Graph.fromEdges(edges, defaultValue = 1)
```

I'm able to create the graph but not able to convert to adjacent matrix representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to approach is something this:

1. Convert `RDD` to `DataFrame`

   ```
   val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
     ("a", "developer"), ("b", "tester"), ("b", "developer"),
     ("c","developer"), ("c", "architect")))

   val df = rdd.toDF("row", "col")
   ```
2. Index columns:

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer

   val indexers = Seq("row", "col").map(x =>
     new StringIndexer().setInputCol(x).setOutputCol(s"${x}_idx").fit(df)
   )
   ```
3. Transform data and create `RDD[MatrixEntry]`:

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.functions.lit
   import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.{MatrixEntry, CoordinateMatrix}


   val entries = indexers.foldLeft(df)((df, idx) => idx.transform(df))
     .select($"row_idx", $"col_idx", lit(1.0))
     .as[MatrixEntry]  // Spark 1.6. For < 1.5 map manually
     .rdd
   ```
4. Create matrix

   ```
   new CoordinateMatrix(entries)
   ```

This matrix can be further converted to any other type of distributed matrix including `RowMatrix` and `IndexedRowMatrix`.

Comment: I mapped manually for spark 1.4, but the ordering of the adjacency matrix is different, first row and third row are interchanged, any pointers for this.

Comment: It doesnt seem to work for spark 1.6.2. Error: `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'i' given input columns: [row_idx, col_idx, 1]`.